# Incompatible types : String cannot be converted to int error in java

Tags: java

I've checked my codes many times but not seeing any error in lines. But It shows `incompatible types: string cannot be converted to int` in the package name. I've tried copying all codes in new package also but still seeing the same error. What was the exact problem. Here is my error screenshot
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdxnu.png)

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: share your build-impl.xml and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the actual error you are showing currently, I was having the same issue earlier, But I found my error that was

**Passed String which takes int as parameter**

May be you have done something like this

It's your method :

```
public void doSomething(int param){
  //Do something
}
```

And you maybe calling this by passing indirect (or may be direct sometime) string like

```
doSomething(someEditText.getText());
```

**NOTE: This may not show error directly to line number, instead this may show incompatible types error at package name.**

Comment: This will result in the error "error: method doSomething in class X cannot be applied to given types; required: int, found: String" on the line number of the line that tries to invoke doSomething. It doesn't show it at the package name.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I thought the same, direct passing will show an error but when I was trying to get text from JTextField and pass to method, It showed once.. I was so confused at that time, and didn't get any idea what to do, Once the mistake was solved by passing the value after parsing it to int.. I can provide you that code soon if you need,...It was a netbeans swing project... I was also surprised when the error showed at package name not in the line number...

Comment: Really I got it... this was error.. I was using this line  `int result = deleteFromDatabase(txtDel);` for this `public int deleteFromDatabase(int id){}`.... Thank you very much